# Plotly express or Go - Labels inside Counties for a map

Tags: dictionary, label, plotly

I am trying to **put a label on tiles** based on a “CHANGE” or “COUNTY” item as shown below. I couldnt achieve it. Below is my sample code.

```
fig = px.choropleth(stat_data, geojson=geo_json_data, color="CHANGE",
                    locations="COUNTY", featureidkey="properties.COUNTY",
                    projection="mercator",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn, color_continuous_midpoint=2
                          )

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

I tried with plotlyexpress or go method with the advice shown on [answer on other forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/labels-inside-counties-for-a-map/13953) looks like it only works for figure factory since scatter method is only available for that one.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

I  found an answer on here : https://community.plotly.com/t/annotations-on-plotly-choropleth/36219

```
fig.add_scattergeo(
  geojson=counties,
  locations = df['names'],
  text = df['values'],
  featureidkey="properties.NAME_3",
  mode = 'text')
```